# How to assign the value to varialable using java.lang.reflect package in java

Tags: java, reflection

I am doing my project in university using java, I have got stuck to assign value to variable. In my class I have few fields without values. However, I want to provide value to variable reading from database each time when class constructor is called. Now, there are 7 fields in my class for example and from that there will be use of only one field based on execution, now I want to assign value to that field(s) at run time. Means, if there is only two field which will be used then I want to assign value to only those two fields. I will get the field name from database with value, so I will check if the field name is matching then I will assign the value to variable. OR if there is any other value to handle this.

Below given code is not working, syntax error

I would appreciate your inputs.

```
package RandD;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class Reflection {

public static final String field1="";
static final int field2=0;
private final String field3="";
static String field4="";
protected String field5="";
List<String> element1;
HashMap<String, Integer> element2;

public Reflection() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    test();
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    new Reflection().test();
}

public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    Field[] field = Reflection.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field fd:field){
        if(fd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("field3")){
            fd.getName()="Hello World";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `fd.set(this, "Hello World")`

Comment: `field3` is `final`.

Comment: As an aside, if you are fairly new to Java (which I suspect you are, given the syntax error) I would steer clear of reflection to start with. Learn the basics of the language first, then move on to tricky things like reflection.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev, Thanks for your reply I have run below code but it does not display any output

Comment: public Reflection() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
  test();
 }
 
 
 public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
  Field[] field = Reflection.class.getDeclaredFields();
  
  for(Field fd:field){
   if(fd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("field3")){
    fd.set(this, "Hello World");
   }
  }
  System.out.println(field3);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough you can access and modify private variables through reflection, use it sparingly.

Sample code to set private fields.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ReflectionDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Field[] fields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
            A a = new A();
            for ( Field field:fields ) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                    field.set(a, "StackOverFlow");
                    System.out.println("A.name="+field.get(a));
                }
                if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("age")){
                    field.set(a, 20);
                    System.out.println("A.age="+field.get(a));
                }
                if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("rep")){
                    field.set(a,"New Reputation");
                    System.out.println("A.rep="+field.get(a));
                }
                if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("count")){
                    field.set(a,25);
                    System.out.println("A.count="+field.get(a));
                }
            }               
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class A {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private final String rep;
    private static int count=0;

    public A(){
        name = "Unset";
        age = 0;
        rep = "Reputation";
        count++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
java ReflectionDemo
A.name=StackOverFlow
A.age=20
A.rep=New Reputation
A.count=25
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error comes from the line:

```
fd.getName()="Hello World";
```

Replace it with

```
fd.set(this, "Hello World");
```

The result of `getName()` is a string constant. You cannot assign something to a string constant.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: the instance that the field is to be set on, and the value to be set.

***Your code, however, is trying to set the value of a `final` field, which, although with the code below will compile, will still fail at runtime as you cannot modify a final field.***

But here how:

```
//First, have at hand the instance on which to set the value:
Reflection reflection = new reflection();

for(Field fd:field){
    if(fd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("field3")){
        fd.setAccessible(true);
        fd.set(reflection, "Hello World");
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, you should expect a runtime exception as "field3" is final.

If the target field is static, such as `field1`, you could pass `null` to the first parameter:

```
for(Field fd:field){
    if(fd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("field1")){
        fd.setAccessible(true);
        fd.set(null, "Hello World");
    }
}
```

As a side note, instead of looping and matching on a hard-coded name, you could simply get the field by name:

```
Field field1 = Reflection.class.getDeclaredField("field1");
field1.setAccessible(true);
field1..set(null, "Hello World");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried using getDeclaredField() method but it will only get the public fields. Also, I have tried your both the code snippet but it does not print any things and yes I am calling test method in constructor and I think final variable can be initialize in constructor

Comment: @KarimNarsindani, fd.setAccessible(true); will allow you to access private fields

Comment: @Ravindra after adding fd.setAsscessible(true) I was able to set the value for variable and it is working as expected Many Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele : No exception has been thrown after setting final variable with reflection.

Comment: @RavindraBabu: That's because of setAccessible(true). From java.lang.reflect.Field's javadocs: "...If the underlying field is final, the method throws an IllegalAccessException unless setAccessible(true) has succeeded for this Field object and the field is non-static. Setting a final field in this way is meaningful only during deserialization or reconstruction of instances of classes with blank final fields, before they are made available for access by other parts of a program..." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)